# In Android: How to Force refresh (update) of a TextView that is INSIDE a Dialog Window?

Tags: android, textview, modal-dialog

This is probably a basic procedure, and in fact I've been extensively searching for a suitable answer, but I haven't found anything usable or that actually works. Now, the case:

A Dialog window is placed inside a method:

```
 public void method_with_Dialog_code() {
     Dialog simpleDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.FilterDialogTheme);
     simpleDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_xml_layout);
     simpleDialog.setCancelable(true);

     TextView insideTextView = (TextView) simpleDialog.findViewById( R.id.insidetextview );
     insideTextView.setText("This text should change when the WiFi is offline");

     simpleDialog.show();
 }
```

The respective dialog_xml_layout.xml file is simply:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/insidetextview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

If the device is for example disconnected from the Internet, it generates a message that should be shown in the insideTextView. But notice that simpleDialog and insideTextView are inside the method, so they are local objects, so the first issue is how to execute:

```
     insideTextView.setText("This device is now offline");
```

from another part of the code, that is, outside of the method?
If I decide to make simpleDialog and insideTextView as Global variables, I can with no problem, from another part of the program, set the line:

```
     insideTextView.setText("This device is now offline");
```

But the instruction doesn't work. The TextView is never updated with the new message.

So, any ideas? Maybe with TextView.addTextChangedListener, so insideTextView could be updated when the TextView.setText is executed externally?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

make insideTextView a member variable of the class and use it later.

Comment: First, thanks for your interest. This way we all help each other to improve.

Comment: It seems that I solved it myself: Just declare `TextView insideTextView` as a **GLOBAL** element, that is, outside of the `method_with_Dialog_code()`, but do the instance initialization inside of the method: `insideTextView = (TextView) simpleDialog.findViewById( R.id.insidetextview );` so when I execute the instruction: `insideTextView.setText("This device is now offline");` somewhere else in the code (outside of the method), the new message will show up.